# Show div only when it crosses a certain length

Tags: html, angular

There's over 25 `questions` listed in JSON. I'm trying to show the div only when the user has crossed the 5th question out of the 25 questions. How can I go about this?

Here's where I'm stuck:

```
<div *ngIf="questions.length > 5">{{(questionIndex+1)}}/{{(questions.length)}}</div>
```

Comment: what does it mean to "_crossed the 5th question_" ?

Comment: There's 25 questions and a user is attempting one by one. I want to show the div when the users reach the 5th question. I want to show the DIV between 5th and 25th question. Hide it from 1-4 question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be checked based on `index` not on length of the question.
`<div *ngIf="questionIndex > 5">{{(questionIndex+1)}}/{{(questions.length)}}</div>`